# Integrating Django with Apache while handling regular HTTP requests

Tags: django, apache, http, integration, httprequest

I've got Django running on my Apache server. However, my boss asks me if I can keep the http functionality on Apache. i.e.:regular pages(No in Django directory) should be processed as regular http requests, not handed over to Django.

For example, say I have career.mysite.com hosting Django, I need career.mysite.com/~jose/ or career.mysite.com/111.html be processed as regular page. Since this URL is not in any of my urls.py in Django, right now the page is just displayed as "Internal Server Error". (and a list of URLs in Django if the debug mode is on).

My site setting in /etc/apache2/sites-available is like the following:

```
<VirtualHost career.mysite.com:80>
   ServerName career.mysite.com
   ServerAlias career.mysite.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/career.mysite.com
   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/career.mysite.com/Wiki/django.wsgi
   <Directory /srv/www/career.mysite.com/Wiki>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Wiki is where the Django modules are and django.wsgi is the WSGI file.

Thanks!

Comment: here's the documentation of apache-alias ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html )